# Quiero mostrar una ventana modal despues que el usuario inicie sesion en ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

cuando las credenciales son correctas no tengo problema y muestro la ventana modal. pero si las credenciales son incorrectas también me aparece. Lo estoy manejando con un evento Onclick del boton iniciar sesion, y para saber si hay una autenticacion utilizo Request.IsAuthenticated. La idea con eso era si es falsa tengo oculto el modal y si es verdadera mostrarla. Pero no me funciona a la hora que suceda un inicio de sesión invalido.

este es el codigo que tengo del modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Bienvenido</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p align="center">Bienvenido al sistema CRISEB.</p>
            <p align="center">Precione Aceptar para continuar.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Aceptar</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

luego el codigo del boton donde llama la funcion de javascript:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Iniciar sesión" class="btn btn-default" onclick="MostrarMensajeDeBienvenida()"/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

y este es el codigo JS:

```
<script>

function MostrarMensajeDeBienvenida() {


    if ('@Request.IsAuthenticated'== false) {

        $('#myModal').modal('hide')

    } else {

        $('#myModal').modal('show')

    }

}
```

creo que el problema que tengo es cuando se hace el post al iniciar sesion y la pagina esta cargando, cuando hay un inicio de sesion incorrecto

Comment: Muy buenas Alvaro, primero de todo seria bueno que añadieras el código que has intentado hasta ahora para que podamos ayudarte, por otro lado, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso ganes tu primera **medalla**, 
también es muy importante que leas [Ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad y aquí te dejo un [mcve]

Comment: Gracias por las observaciones.

Answer (score 0):

El `'@Request.IsAuthenticated'` te está devolviendo true o false, pero como cadena de texto en vez de booleano, por lo que el la condición debería ser:

`if ('@Request.IsAuthenticated'== 'False') {...}`

Atención a la 'F' mayúscula.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!